# hibernate4, spring 3: No Session found for current thread

Tags: multithreading, spring, session, hibernate-4.x

I've seen several similar questions, but none of the suggested solutions helped me.

Detail, it's a simple exemple :

File: **MandatTypeBean.xml**

```
<bean id="mandatTypeDAO" class="gestint.data.dao.impl.MandatTypeDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ActionMandatType" class="gestint.data.action.MandatTypeAction">
    <property name="mandatTypeDAO" ref="mandatTypeDAO" />
</bean>
```

File: **HibernateSessionFactory.xml**

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

   <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="DataSource"/>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  
         </props>
    </property>


    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
          <value>gestint/data/model/MandatType.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>  
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

File: **MandatTypeDAO.java**

```
public class MandatTypeDAOImpl implements MandatTypeDAO {
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
     this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}   

public List<MandatType> listMandatType() {      
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().isConnected();       

    return null;
}
```

}

File: **MandatTypeAction.java**

```
public class MandatTypeAction extends ActionSupport{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private MandatTypeDAO mandatTypeDAO;    
    private List<MandatType> mandatList = new ArrayList<MandatType>();

    public void setMandatTypeDAO(MandatTypeDAO mandatTypeDAO) {
        this.mandatTypeDAO = mandatTypeDAO;
    }

    public List<MandatType> getMandatTypeList() {
        return mandatList;
    }

    public String listMandatType() {            
        mandatList = mandatTypeDAO.listMandatType();
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

}

And my error..

When I try to acces to 
`public List<MandatType> listMandatType()` 
with a simple linge for testing :

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().isConnected();
```

I get this error :

> 17:02:28,062 ERROR Dispatcher:38 - Exception occurred during
>   processing request: No Session found for current thread
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:980)
>     at
>   gestint.data.dao.impl.MandatTypeDAOImpl.listMandatType(MandatTypeDAOImpl.java:21)
>     at
>   gestint.data.action.MandatTypeAction.listMandatType(MandatTypeAction.java:26)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:446)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:285)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:544)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3288)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1512)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)  at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

Somebody can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line in your `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

Then decorate your `MandateTypeAction` class with `@Transactional` annotation and will be propagated by default (default is propagation type REQUIRED) to the called methods.

Then the transaction will be injected to the `MandateTypeAction`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you injecting the `SessionFactory`? Just use the `Session` directly:

```
@Repository
public Mydao {

   @PersistenceContext
   private Session session;

   @Transactional
   public void persist(entity e) {
       session.persist(e);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for your support ! It works,

The solutions is :

I add annotation-driven 
File: **HibernateSessionFactory.xml**

```
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

And I add the annotions to the DAO
File: **MandatTypeDAO.java**

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface MandatTypeDAO {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    List<MandatType> listMandatType();  
}
```